# How does nmap ping/scan a target?

Tags: networking, ping, nmap

My IP address is 172.20.35.3, I'm trying `nmap -sn 172.20.35.100` and monitoring the traffic using wireshark. The ping is successful, however wireshark only shows a DNS query request sent from 172.20.35.3 to the DNS server and the DNS replies with no such name! Monitoring the traffic on my target IP address shows no incoming frames. So I'm curious about where `nmap` is getting the information from (MAC address for instance).

P.S: I thought `nmap` might be simply searching in the ARP table for a suitable entry. So I tried again after flushing the ARP table, but the result was the same.

Comment: Where are you running wireshark?

Comment: wireshark running on 172.20.35.3 (my PC) the target is an embedded linux device.

Comment: Hmm. After searching further, it seems the -sn option is actually the same as -sP (nmap changes -sP automatically to -sn once I run the command). The -sP is documented in the nmap book. However I was actually expecting the target to receive an ICMP echo request, since it is in the same subnet as the host. That DNS thing is still puzzling me. If I change the IP-address of the target to be on a different subnet than the host, then it all makes sense. ICMP echo followed by TCP ping.

Comment: @hhachem `-sn` is the new name for `-sP`, added in version 5.21 (January 2010).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about networking not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nmap's [host discovery](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html) engine is robust and uses many kinds of probes to determine whether a host is up on a network. The term "ping" is used for this kind of activity, which can be confusing, since it usually refers to [ICMP Echo Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29#Message_format) (Type 8 Code 0) and Echo Response (Type 0 Code 0).

What is most likely happening here is that Nmap is sending an [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) request for the target IP address, and marking it as "up" when it gets a positive response. This is the method Nmap uses when running with sufficient privilege against addresses in your interface's broadcast domain.

For other hosts, the default host discovery probes are (in order): ICMP Echo Request, TCP SYN to port 443, TCP ACK to port 80, and ICMP Timestamp Request. Note that if you are running without root/administrator privileges (or using the `--unprivileged` option), host discovery is done with a TCP SYN and full handshake to port 80 and 443, regardless of broadcast domain.

The DNS request is sent for all hosts that Nmap finds up. You can disable it with the `-n` argument.